# Find a Row in Excel file based on a column value and Update the row value using ClosedXML

Tags: closedxml

I have an excel file as shown below. I would like to find a row in excel using a column Value (like SubmissionID == 2) and then update the email address of the particular row

[image: Excel File]

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(filestream))
{
     var ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
     var range = ws.RangeUsed();
     var lastRow = range.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();

    // not able to find the column
     using (var rows = ws.RowsUsed(r => r.FirstCell().GetString() == "SubmissionID"))
     {
          foreach (var row in rows)
          {
                        // Do something with the row...
          }
      }
```

}

Comment: Sidenote: in the upcoming v0.93 release, the `using` statement on the rows will no longer be allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using

```
using (var rows = ws.RowsUsed(r => r.FirstCell().GetString() == "2"))
```

or

```
using (var rows = ws.RowsUsed(r => r.FirstCell().Value == 2))
```